# Check whether the value is a date, integer, or a string in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

```
    <script>
    var dateNow = new Date();
    var dateNow2 = dateNow.toDateString()
    var dateToday = new Date(prompt("Enter Date"))

    var dateToday1 = dateToday.toDateString()

    var dateToday2 = dateToday.getTime()
    var dateToday4 = Number(dateToday2)

    if (dateToday1 === dateNow2) {
       alert("Yes, today is" + " " + dateNow2)
    } 
       else if ((dateToday1 !== dateNow2) || (dateToday1 < dateNow2)){ 
       alert("No, today is" + " " + dateNow2)
    } 
       else if (typeof dateToday4 === "number"){ 
       !isNaN(dateToday4)
       alert("Follow Date Format")
    }
       else {
       alert("Check Date Format")
    }
    </script>
```

I'm writing a script that will evaluate an entered date (using the `toDateString` format), I wanted it also to check if the user entered an integer (E.g. 5, 6, 9, etc), it will display a specific text. And will also evaluate if the user entered a string (E.g. Cat, dog, etc.) that is not a format of a date, it will also display a specific text.

Comment: There is no "integer" type in JavaScript.

Comment: @Pointy still doesn't work